# how to capture video duration programmatically?

Tags: android-intent

in my app im capturing video with the time duration 10sec.using the method EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT.my code runs perfectly in sony 2.3.but in other obile like htc and lg.my time duration extends more than 10 sec... how to rectify that

my code is:

```
Intent videoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
videoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, limit);
videoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
startActivityForResult(videoIntent, ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO);
```

is there any other way to limit the time duration??

Comment: Intent videoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
videoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, limit);
videoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
startActivityForResult(videoIntent, ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO);

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

            Uri videofileuri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);  // create a file to save the video
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,videofileuri);  // set the image file name
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1); 
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT,10);

            // start the Video Capture Intent
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```